# How to resolve class-name conflicts between two third-party libraries that do not use namespaces?

Tags: c++, namespaces

My project uses two third-party open-source libraries, both libraries define type `BDD`, and both do not use namespaces.

Is there a way to resolve the name conflict? Maybe force one library into a custom namespace?

Additional info:
the first library uses `BDD` only as type alias (`typedef int BDD`), so it does not call any methods on `BDD`.

Comment: You probably need to create some wrapper for one of them, that does not `#include` the conflicting header in the header of your wrapper component. Some sort of [pimpl](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/pimpl) perhaps? There is some messy overhead to this, as you would pretty much need to duplicate the interface of the class (member and non-member functions), and have the definitions just forward to the library versions of those functions.

Comment: Are they open-source libraries?

Comment: Do you mean both BDD's are `#define`?

Comment: Also, do they have a compiled component?

Comment: One more question: you tagged this as C++, but are the libraries in C++, or are they C libraries and you're just using them from C++?

Comment: @GoranFlegar thanks for the answer and comments, I am trying it  now. Both libraries are C++ (although internally they use C)

Comment: @YSC, yes, they are open-source, but quite huge to manually change the names.

Comment: @Ayrat what does "they are C++ but internally use C" mean? As for YSC's comment, I don't think he's aiming for changing the names, but wrapping everything in namespaces. which is a constant amount of work per source file.

Comment: @GoranFlegar why did you remove your answer? it actually worked, and I plan to use it. ("internally use C" -- that was irrelevant piece of info, sorry, but what happened is that the first lib was simply using BDD as `typedef int BDD`, so yours' define-undefine trick works there).

Comment: @Ayrat I removed it because YSC's answer is a better approach if the libraries are open source (you make the world a better place, which you don't if you use my answer) :)

Comment: However, it is a lot simpler to use my answer in your specific scenario, so I'll unremove it and edit it to include the new information.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since one of your libraries only uses `BDD` as an alias for `int` (I'll assume this library is called `lib1`, and the other `lib2`), you can just change the name of this alias by telling the preprocessor to rename it before including the library, like so:

```
#define BDD BDD_lib1
#include <lib1>
#undef BDD

#include <lib2>
```

If you ever need to use the name `BDD` from `lib1` in your code, you can then reference it with `BDD_lib1` (or just with `int` if you're not worried that its type can change in a future version of `lib1`).

---

However, I would consider this approach only a workaround, and not a true solution, so you may want to consider doing as @YSC suggested in his answer and provide a patch so other people trying to use the libraries do not run into the same problem.

---

### Does this work in a more general scenario?

If `BDD` was not just a simple type alias, but a separate class, one could run into trouble due to C++'s name mangling, so this method would only work if the name `BDD` is not important in any scenarios where name mangling would appear. This imposes more or less the following restrictions:

- `BDD` must not have any non-inline methods
- any types depending on `BDD` (e.g. a specialization `A<BDD>` of class template `template <typename> class A;` is a type depending on `BDD) must not have any non-inline methods
- all functions/methods whose argument list includes types depending on `BDD` must either be inline, or have C linkage

Comment: Your edit is, I think, the real added value of your answer. +1

Comment: Thanks, that's why I added it - it is unlikely that anyone else searching for this will have the exact same situation as the OP, so I figured it was a good idea to explain when this could and when it couldn't work.

Answer (score 4):

Since those libraries are open-sourced, you can add a namespace to at least one of them and provide your patch to the library maintainer.

You'll achieve two things:

1. fix your specific naming clash, and
2. make the World a better place.

Comment: And by _you can_, I mean _you should_.